# What's the shortest way to detect the highest value among variables?

Tags: javascript

I have three variables with varying outputs:

```
a = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
b = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
c = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
```

Assuming that no variable will ever be equal, how would I detect which has the highest value?

Comment: The answer is always C. lol

Comment: I feel like there's a command that I don't know that could easily solve this.

Comment: There's `Math.max(a,b,c)` if there's only ever three, but I don't know if that matches "shortest way". There's different ways of interpreting (fewest keystrokes, most efficient algo, etc).

Comment: @Thaadikkaaran That would be if there number of values was variable, so that's a goodly suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `Math.max()` method:

`var max = Math.max(a, b, c);`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Cool, if you like you can accept and upvote my answer =)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
a = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
b = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
c = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
var max = Math.max(a, b, c);
console.log(a, b, c, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you have a variable number of inputs, simply use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
let arr = [3,1,4,6,3]
arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b)) // 6
```

This is what @Thaadikkaaran posted in a since-deleted comment (AFAIR).

Here's a methodology where it would generate then give the maximal value, although in practice doing this with `Match.random()` *I don't think* makes sense:

```
Array(3).fill(Math.random() * 10000).reduce((a,b) => Math.max(a,b))
```

And the winner for conciseness (if you follow the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)):

```
Math.max(...[2,3,1,5,6,]) // 6
```

Which could then be used generatively:

```
Math.max(...Array(3).fill(Math.random() * 10000))
```

e.g.:

```
function maxFromRandom(n, s) {
    return Math.max(
        ...Array(n).fill(Math.random() * s)
    )
} 
maxFromRandom(3, 10000)
```

Comment: ofc instead of setting the variable for `a`, `b`, or `c` OP would have to append them to the array using `(array).push(value)`..

Comment: @TyQ.That is one way, of course if it's something of the sort like these are simply generative, it could also be: `Array(3).fill(Math.random() * 10000).reduce((a,b) => Math.max(a,b))`

Comment: Simpler to use `Math.max.apply` on array or spread operator in es6 ... `Math.max(...arr)`

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, I was trying to figure out how to do the spread operator. This is at least a little more human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

if using underscore

```
let a = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
let b = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
let c = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000);
let max = _.max([a,b,c])
console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bunch of [conditional (ternary) operators `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

I suggest to use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), because it is made foe numbers and their integer equivalent. The [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function is made for string parsing for a number with a given radix.

```js
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    max = a > b
        ? a > c
            ? a
            : c
        : b > c
            ? b
            : c;

console.log(a, b, c, max);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should push those variables's name into an array, and create another array to contain related value for each variable, here my script:

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c'];
var array2 = [];
function findMaxVar(){
    for(let i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
     array2.push(Math.random() * 10000);
    return array1[array2.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,array2))];
}

console.log(findMaxVar());
```